# Inserting Integers into a TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

I want to store the IDs of items and their corresponding co-ordinates. For this, I'm using a TreeMap where Coordinates is a class containing int x and int y. Now, for inserting data into the map can I write:

```
treeMapObject.put(5,new BasicRow(30,90));
```

Or do I have to write:

```
treeMapObject.put(new Integer(5),new BasicRow(30,90));
```

I guess only the second one is correct because Maps deal with objects. But now the question is, say I have the following piece of code:

```
treeMapObject.put(new Integer(5),new BasicRow(30,90));
treeMapObject.put(new Integer(5),new BasicRow(45,85));
```

In such a case what will happen?

Comment: In my above code snippet, can BasicRow be an inner class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

actually both versions are correct, because your Java compiler will perform what is called "autoboxing" for you: If you supply an int, where an Integer is required, java will automatically wrap that int in an Integer object for you. This works vice-versa as well (has been introduced in Java 5. If you'd use an older Java version that should not even compile.).

For your second question: The entry you added first will be overwritten.

Comment: @Andreas: ok, stripped the identical ;-)

Answer (score 1):

yankee is right, both will work, because Java will [autobox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) the integer values into an `Integer` object.

Note that if you want to do this explicitly, it is better to write:

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

instead of:

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
```

If you use `valueOf`, then class `Integer` can avoid creating a new `Integer` object, it will return a pre-existing `Integer` object from its internal cache, which is more efficient than creating a new object.

Comment: @aps yes, there's nothing special about inner classes that would prevent you from using them as values in a map.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference, which does not affect the behaviour of the map. In both cases, if you try to *get* the value for integer 5, the map will return that basic row.

The difference: the second line will always create a new instance of `Integer` while the first one may insert an existing instance. But maps compare by *equality*, not by *identity*, so it actually doesn't matter. Just that the first line has a (very) small postive impact on memory consumption.